# Using IxEdit in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-gears

I read about IxEdit on Stackoverflow and I want to try it.  My favorite browser for doing Javascript is Firefox.

The problem is that Google Gears is a dependency for Ixedit and that seems to have been deprecated.  Is there any way to get Google Gears to work in Firefox 10 or any way to get IxEdit to work otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a modified version of IxEdit that doesn't require Google Gears: https://github.com/perchouli/ixedit

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. If you're running less than Snow Leopard, you can download Gears from http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25083/google-gears

Looks like we'll have to settle with Safari/Chrome. From the IxEdit site... "If you choose Safari or Chrome, you don’t need to install Gears."